# PHP script that auto populates "most popular" articles?

Tags: php, scripting

I'm new to programming. Do you know how a lot of WP blogs have a "most popular" article feature within their software. What would the scripting code look like? I can't seem to imagine it would be a difficult syntax but I'm trying to figure out how it's actually written. Thanks again everyone for your help!

Comment: can you share some notes or attempts?

Comment: Why not look at the plugins at the [WordPress plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) site? Either way, there are different ways to calculate what's popular, could be by views, comments, a mixture, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this plugin: [WP Most Popular](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-most-popular/)

Good luck!